# Add a value to the INSERTED table AFTER INSERT trigger was used

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

My task is to create a trigger on SQL Server which will react on each INSERT event on a table.

Example of inserted table of the trigger:
[image]

When new rows are added to the inserted table a trigger will be fired and will take the value in ID on row 1 and will insert it into ValStr on row 2

What I did so far was creating a trigger that does this process on a different table, not the one that was inserted after the trigger was fired.

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tblLLAttrData]
   ON  [dbo].[LLAttrData]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DataId int = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED where AttrID = 2)
    DECLARE @Department nvarchar(255) = (SELECT ValStr FROM INSERTED where AttrID = 2)    
    DECLARE @DepCode nvarchar(255) = (  SELECT distinct Department.dep_code 
    FROM ayalon_department AS Department, dbo.LLAttrData AS Attr 
    WHERE Attr.ValStr = Department.dep_name and Attr.AttrID = 2 and Attr.ValStr = @Department)

    INSERT INTO dbo.ExternalTable
    values (@DataId + '_' @DepCode '_' + 'NTA')
END
```

I have declared @DataId in order to keep the value from the inserted table and then pass it to the external table. I'm looking to pass it to the same inserted table.

Comment: Why don't you just join `inserted` and `ayalon_department`? You don't need the first two `DECLARE`s at all, nor do you need to filter `inserted`

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ID FROM INSERTED where AttrID = 2` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: `What I did so far was creating a trigger that does this process on a different table, not the one that was inserted after the trigger was fired.` What is the reason for this ?

Comment: @marc_s is completely right here. This trigger is never going to work as you expect if you ever `INSERT` 2 or more rows. It doesn't even matter if currently you ***think*** that's all you'll ever insert; requirements *will* change and when they do things aren't going to work.

Comment: @marc_s it's as it should be. It seems to be working so far. I need to get that value inserted at the 2nd row our of 12 rows and insert it in the 9th inserted row. I don't mind ignoring other rows.

Comment: You seem to be under the false impression that rows have a specific order within a table and that you can access (or insert) the "9th" row. You can't unless there is a set of columns (or just one) that determines this order you want. But there are other flaws - including some unmentioned like the old-style joins - that suggest you should start over. Rather than focus on "how", focus on "what". What are you trying to accomplish? Your use of generic table names provides no clues about your goal, so perhaps that is sign of deeper issues.